# return first non repeating character in a string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I had  to solve this question in which given a string, i had to return the first non repeating character present in the string.

I solved it using hashtable and wrote a method which takes a constant reference to the string and returns the first non repeating character. However, when there is no non repeating character present in the string, i return -1 and in the main program i check as follows

```
char c = firstNonRepeating( word );
if (static_cast<int> (c) == -1)
     cout<<"no non repeating character present\n";
else
     cout<<c<<endl;
```

is that the correct way to return -1 when required character is not present?

Answer (score 2):

You can `return` simply `0`. Because logically, in any case `0` is the first non-repeating character in any nul-terminated string !

I think returning `-1` is error prone because you do a casting to `int` and moreover `255` is also a valid character.

Comment: string may not necessarily be null terminated...thats only a c way to indicate the end of the string

Comment: @Amm Sokun, But in your logic, you will check the string only till null .. correct. So in such case it's a valid idea. If you check for size of the character array then you can argue, but you mentioned `string` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a matter of style, but I would rather go for something like:

```
char c;
bool result = getFirstNonRepeating(word, c);

if (result)
     cout << "no non repeating character present\n";
else
     cout << c << endl;
```

Where `c`'s value after the call is unspecified if `getFirstNonRepeating` returns `false`.

That way, there is no ambiguity between the return value and the result (or failure) of the operation, and your `getFirstNonRepeating` function can work even for `'\0'` or `0xFF` characters if you ever need to change the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more option: to be more similar to STL algorithms you may return iterator to the first non-repeating character, in case of its absence simply return string.end().

Answer (score 0):

I have used HashMap to count characters

```
FirstNonRepeating(String s){
HashMap<Character, Integer> count = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    int n = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        count.put(c, count.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }

    // find & print the index position 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (count.get(s.charAt(i)) == 1) 
            System.out.println(i); 
}
```